# How to compute inverse of a wave sound file in Python?

Tags: python, signal-processing, wave, noise-reduction

I am trying to compute inverse of a 16 bit mono wave file(8000Hz) using Python without using almost any external module except `wave` which is used to read samples from the wave file. I've tried reading all the 16 bit samples and computing `0xFFFF - sample` for each sample and writing that to another wave file. But when I mix the two audio files together, they don't silence each other. I've read some stuff on the internet about DFT, FFT and such these but I don't understand much from them even through I've got a strong mathematics background from highschool. Any hint is appreciated. My code:

```py
import wave
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List


@dataclass
class SoundClip16b:
    data: List["int"]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def inverted(self):
        inv = list()
        for d in self.data:
            inv.append(0xFFFF - d)
        return SoundClip16b(data=inv)

    def to_bytes(self):
        databyte = b""
        for i in self.data:
            b1 = i >> 8
            b2 = i & 0xFF
            databyte += bytes([b1, b2])
        return databyte

    @staticmethod
    def from_bytes(bytedata):
        data = list()
        for index, byte in enumerate(bytedata[:-1:2]):
            next_byte = bytedata[index+1]
            data.append((byte << 8) + next_byte)

        return SoundClip16b(data=data)


w_noise = wave.open("noise.wav")
w_antinoise = wave.open("antinoise.wav", "w")
clip = SoundClip16b.from_bytes(w_noise.readframes(-1))
inverted_clip = clip.inverted()
w_antinoise.setnchannels(1)
w_antinoise.setsampwidth(2)
w_antinoise.setframerate(8000)
w_antinoise.writeframes(inverted_clip.to_bytes())
w_antinoise.close()
```

Edit: I also have tried by assuming that the 16 bit samples are signed integers rather than unsigned ones.

Comment: Why don't use `struct` to handle the conversion to bytes and deal with the byteorder? Are you sure the data is big endian?

Comment: Hi Jan. I've used `struct` too for signed numbers. Data is in little endian.

Comment: It's much easier to use `struct.unpack` and `struct.pack` to handle the data. `struct.unpack_iter('<h', w_noise.readframes(-1))` will yield 16-bit signed numbers. You only need to take the twos complement of those (`~x`) to invert them.

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'struct' has no attribute 'unpack_iter'`

Comment: Sorry, it's `iter_unpack`. My memory didn't serve me right. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jan, the problem was with endianess. The wave was little endian while my code was assuming it was big endian. This code worked for me right:

```py
import wave
import struct
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List


@dataclass
class SoundClip16b:
    data: List["int"]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def inverted(self):
        inv = list()
        for d in self.data:
            inv.append(~d)
        return SoundClip16b(data=inv)

    def to_bytes(self):
        databyte = b""
        for d in self.data:
            databyte += struct.pack("<h", d)
        return databyte

    @staticmethod
    def from_bytes(bytedata):
        return SoundClip16b(
            data=[x[0] for x in struct.iter_unpack("<h", bytedata)]
        )


w_noise = wave.open("noise.wav")
w_antinoise = wave.open("antinoise.wav", "w")
clip = SoundClip16b.from_bytes(w_noise.readframes(-1))
inverted_clip = clip.inverted()
w_antinoise.setnchannels(1)
w_antinoise.setsampwidth(2)
w_antinoise.setframerate(8000)
w_antinoise.writeframes(inverted_clip.to_bytes())
w_antinoise.close()
```